# emit signal from thread

Tags: qt, multithreading

I am writing a sample which uses thread to do some background processing.

In the thread I am trying to emitting a signal. But it is not coming to slot.

While connecting I checked the value of “connect()” function value , it is returning value as true.

One thing to notice is in the run method I am not using “exec() “ .

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void run( void )
    {
        while (true)
        {
            emit updateStatus();
        }
    }

signals:
    void updateStatus();

};



class test: public  QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public :
    void test
    {
        connect(&thread, SIGNAL(updateStatus()),this, SLOT(update()));
        thread.start();
    }


public slots:
    void update()
    {
        //display
    }

private:
    MyThread  thread;
};
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you post some code to illustrate your problem..

Comment: Your code works for me (except the wrong declaration of your `test` constructor. You did construct a `QApplication` and called `exec()`on it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be doing that. Your MyThread object is living in main thread, and therefore it's signals should be emited from main thread.
I am not sure what exactly will happen with call like this, but i suspect that connection type will be Qt::DirectConnection (as both MyThread and test live in main thread), and your slot will be called directly in the run method, so not in the main thread (which is, i assume, what you want).

If you want to emit from another thread, you need to create some QObject descendant in MyThread::run, and use it to emit signals.

If qt figured out that you meant queued connection, then it should also work, if you have event loop working in main thread (do you?).